# Working around the need for partial mocks

Tags: ruby, oop, architecture, minitest

From time to time I run into the situation that I want to use partial mocks of class methods in my tests. Currently, I'm working with *minitest* which does not support this (probably because it's not a good idea in the first place...).

An example:

```
class ImportRunner

  def self.run *ids
    ids.each { |id| ItemImporter.new(id).import }
  end
end

class ItemImporter

  def initialize id
    @id = id
  end

  def import
    do_this
    do_that
  end

  private

    def do_this
      # do something with fetched_data
    end

    def do_that
      # do something with fetched_data
    end

    def fetched_data
      @fetched_data ||= DataFetcher.get @id
    end

end
```

I want to test the `ImportRunner.run` method in isolation (mainly because `ItemImporter#import` is slow/expensive). In *rspec* I would have written a test like this:

```
it 'should do an import for each id' do
  first_importer  = mock
  second_importer = mock

  ItemImporter.should_receive(:new).with(123).and_return(first_importer)
  first_importer.should_receive(:import).once
  ItemImporter.should_receive(:new).with(456).and_return(second_importer)
  second_importer.should_receive(:import).once

  ImportRunner.run 123, 456
end
```

**First part of the question:** Is it possible to do something similar in *minitest*?

---

**Second part of the question:** Is object collaboration in the form

```
collaborator = SomeCollaborator.new a_param
collaborator.do_work
```

bad design? If so, how would you change it?

Comment: Have you gone through the [Minitest::Mock](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/mock/rdoc/MiniTest/Mock.html) stuff?

Comment: Yes. `Minitest::Mock` provides full mock objects as well as partial stubbing of methods. But not partial mocking as I would need in this case...

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is *almost* possible in straight Minitest. Minitest::Mock doesn't support partial mocking, so we attempt to do this by stubbing ItemImporter's `new` method and returning a lambda that calls a mock that returns mocks instead. (Mocks within a mock: Mockception)

```
def test_imports_for_each_id
  # Set up mock objects
  item_importer   = MiniTest::Mock.new
  first_importer  = MiniTest::Mock.new
  second_importer = MiniTest::Mock.new

  # Set up expectations of calls
  item_importer.expect :new, first_importer,  [123]
  item_importer.expect :new, second_importer, [456]
  first_importer.expect  :import, nil
  second_importer.expect :import, nil

  # Run the import
  ItemImporter.stub :new, lambda { |id| item_importer.new id } do
    ImportRunner.run 123, 456
  end

  # Verify expectations were met
  # item_importer.verify
  first_importer.verify
  second_importer.verify
end
```

This will work except for calling `item_importer.verify`. Because that mock will return other mocks, the process of verifying all the expectations were met will call additional methods on the `first_importer` and `second_importer` mocks, causing them to raise. So while you can get close, you can't replicate your rspec code exactly. To do that you will have to use a different mocking library that supports partial mocks like [RR](https://github.com/rr/rr).

If that code looks ugly to you, don't worry, it is. But that isn't the fault of Minitest, its the fault of conflicting responsibilities within the test. Like you said, this probably isn't a good idea. I don't know what this test is supposed to prove. It looks to be specifying the implementation of your code, but it isn't really communicating the expected behavior. This is what some folks call "over-mocked".

> Mocks and stubs are important and useful tools in the hands of a developer, but it’s easy to get carried away. Besides lending a false sense of security, over-mocked tests can also be brittle and noisy. - [Rails AntiPatterns](http://www.informit.com/store/rails-antipatterns-best-practice-ruby-on-rails-refactoring-9780321604811)

I would rethink what you are trying to accomplish with this test. Minitest is helping you out here by making the design choice that ugly things should look ugly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did not know that you can pass a proc to *.stub* that is evaluated whenever the stubbed method is invoked. This changes everything ;) I took your implementation and made it even simpler: instead of the `item_importer` mock I define a mapping `importer_mapping = {123 => first_importer, 456 => second_importer}` and then invoke *.stub* with a this proc: `proc {|id| importer_mapping[id]}`. This way, I do not use a mock object without verifying it. The correct call to *.new* is verified implicitly in that the correct importer(s) receive *#import*...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Mocha gem](https://github.com/freerange/mocha). I am also using MiniTest in most of my tests, and using Mocha to mock and stub methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of other mocking frameworks (*mocha*, *rr* and a lot of others). But I'm looking for a solution using only *minitest*... Or for a rewrite that allows testing with *minitest* without having to rely on partial mocks